# Jump to a length of an iframe on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an embeded iframe 2000px high in my website.

I would like to jump at 50% or 1000px of the height of this iframe when i click a button. Then with an other button i would like to jump at 75% or 1500px of the height of the same iframe.

Buttons will be outside the iframe in my website but in the same page with the iframe.

Iframe embeded in my website is from an other domain that I don't own so I have no control over this embedded iframe.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure if you're using Node.js, but if so, you might want to look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-iframe-replacement

Comment: Thank you for the comment but i'm not using Node